# How to use OverlayScrollbars with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am learning `TypeScript` using an `ASP.NET Core 3.0` project and `VS 2019` IDE. I have downloaded `OverlayScrollbars` plugin using `npm`: https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars/#!overview.

```
npm install overlayscrollbars
npm install @types/overlayscrollbars
```

Here is a very simple example of usage:

```
/// <reference path="../../libs/npm/@types/overlayscrollbars/index.d.ts" />

import OverlayScrollbars from "../../libs/npm/@types/overlayscrollbars/index"; // ../../libs/npm/overlayscrollbars/js/overlayscrollbars.js

$(() => {
    OverlayScrollbars($("body")[0], { });
    //$("body").overlayScrollbars({ });
});
```

Solution compiles, files get transpiled (the target is changed to the one in the comment - I am gonna ask question about transpiling one day though) and copied to `wwwroot`. Files are referenced correctly at this point.

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types/**" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

With this: `OverlayScrollbars($("body")[0], { });`, I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'default'` at runtime.

[image]

With the second one (`$("body").overlayScrollbars({ });`), I am getting compilation error `TS2345: (TS) Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type string` and some weird intellisense problem:

[image]

[image]

Solving this in `C#` would have been trivial but I don't have enough knowledge about `TS` to do it. Trying to solve it by trial and error is not very efficient.

Here is a minimalistic project that reproduces this issue:

https://mega.nz/#!9vYGCS6Q!p_jfFXYSo_1yH63UsSWqwsypC_2Lclg57LhirZfdiGI

Would appreciate any attempt of help.

// EDIT 1

@Kewin Dousse

I apologise that I didn't state it clearly, I am referencing the declarations explicitly because I am importing the actual files in my `.cshtml` file.

```
<link href="~/libs/npm/overlayscrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
<script src="~/libs/npm/overlayscrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.js"></script>
```

I specifically did it trying to avoid these problems I am writing here about and it doesn't matter if I am trying to use `JQuery` or Vanilla version of `OVerlayScrollbars`.

The thing is that with imports as far as I understand the browser needs to points to the `JavaScript` file with explicit `.js` extension if I want to make it work.

To address it I am making `gulp` replace the actual path to the `d.ts` file with the one in the comment.

If I do this:

```
import OverlayScrollbars from "../../libs/npm/@types/overlayscrollbars/index"; // ../../libs/npm/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.js
```

I get editor warning in my `.ts` file:

[image]

and error at runtime:

[image]

If I do this:

```
import { OverlayScrollbars } from "../../libs/npm/@types/overlayscrollbars/index"; // ../../libs/npm/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.js
```

I get compilation error `TS2305` with a very weird path:

[image]

If I do this:

```
import * as OverlayScrollbars from "../../libs/npm/@types/overlayscrollbars/index"; // ../../libs/npm/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.js
```

I get compilation error `TS2349`:

[image]

and the following intellisense error:

[image]

(the potential VS fix is turning the path into `import OverlayScrollbars from "../../libs/npm/@types/overlayscrollbars/index";` if you wonder)

The only way I can actually make it work is by writing the declaration for `JQuery` extension myself:

```
interface JQuery {
    overlayScrollbars(
        options: OverlayScrollbars.Options,
        extensions?: OverlayScrollbars.Extensions
    ): JQuery;
    overlayScrollbars(
        filter?: string | ((element: Element, instance: OverlayScrollbars) => boolean)
    ): OverlayScrollbars | OverlayScrollbars[] | undefined;
}
```

calling it like this:

```
$("body").overlayScrollbars({ });
```

and removing module import

I understand that this is also what the declarations file is supposed to be doing and by inspecting its content it seems that it does, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're not importing the actual code for `OverlayScrollbars` in your file, you're currently only importing its type definitions.

On type definitions : `"../../libs/npm/@types/overlayscrollbars/index"` references the [`@types/overlayscrollbars`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/overlayscrollbars) npm package, which is an npm package that contains only [declaration files](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html) (ass all packages under `@types/`). Declaration files are files that add TypeScript types onto JavaScript libraries, so that they can be used efficiently with TypeScript. That means, as they only declare types, there not a single JavaScript line that will be executed there.

Here, you imported that declaration file for your `overlayscrollbars` package, which now makes TypeScript able to understand the types of that JS library. However, you **never actually imported the library code itself**.

You should import the library as if you were writing JS. I don't know what this library exports specifically, but it should look like this :

```
import OverlayScrollbars from "../../libs/npm/overlayscrollbars";
```

If it does not work, also try this :

```
import { OverlayScrollbars } from "../../libs/npm/overlayscrollbars";
```

And this :

```
import * as OverlayScrollbars from "../../libs/npm/overlayscrollbars";
```

as the module might try to export its symbol in a different way. (I can't tell without going into the lib's export and actually see what they look like)

The second error simply tells you that you're invoking `overlayscrollbars` the wrong way, and that the first argument should be a `string`.

Comment: I updated my question, thank you for the response. The error with the `string` is completely out of the blue. I mean `this` technically can be a `string` or a `selector` but this is specified before so I don't know. Lets ignore the `string` error for the moment.

Comment: I see. By putting the JS file in the page "by hand" (`<script src=... />` instead of `import`), that makes TypeScript not aware that the content of the script is effectively available, since you're "bypassing" the module system's imports. Then, I'm sorry but I doubt that I'll be able to help much further now that I understand more of your architecture. I'm not used to .NET nor VS (nor their build system). I thought it was purely a JS/TS issue, but it looks like it has more to do with the actual structure of your project now. Note that if some problem is *only* TS related, you can @ts-ignore it

Comment: But as you can see I followed your instructions and scrapped all of the bypassing here and it still doesn't work. I think that something very easy eludes me here and that it is TS/JS problem. Take a look here: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@types/overlayscrollbars@1.9.0/index.d.ts` how would you import it and to what file would you point your `JS` file? I mean, I am new to `TS`, but it can't be that hard in this case.